# Principle Component Analysis with very big dimension of data

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of samples (vectors) each have a dimension about of M (10000) and the size of the set is also about N(10000), and i want to find first (with biggest eiegenvalues) 10 PC of this set. Due to the big dimension of samples i cannot calculate covariation matrix in reasonable time. Are there any methods to select PC without calculation of full cov matrix or methods that can effectively handle big dimension of data or something like this? So these methods should require less operations than O(M*M*N).

Answer (score 1):

NIPALS -- Non-linear iterative partial least squares

see for example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIPALS

Answer (score 0):

guys, maybe it could help somehow, i have found solution in family of EM-PCA methods (see for example this, http://www.cmlab.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cyy/learning/papers/PCA_RoweisEMPCA.pdf)